# Is "realpath" redundant in $absolutePath = realpath(__DIR__)? Is __DIR__ always canonical absolute path?

Tags: php, filesystems

Is it a sence to do something like

```
 $dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
 // or for php 5.3+:
 $dir = realpath(__DIR__)
```

Or magic constants like **DIR** and **FILE** always returns absolute path, so realpath is redundant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You don't need `realpath()`.**

The documentation of `__FILE__`:

> The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the
>   name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, `__FILE__`
>   **always contains an absolute path** with symlinks resolved whereas in
>   older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

So `__FILE__` returns an absolute path => *`realpath()` unnecessary*

And if you use `__DIR__`:

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of
>   the included file is returned. **This is equivalent to
>   dirname(`__FILE__`)**. This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

`__DIR__` also returns an absolute path because `dirname()` doesn't cut off the absolute part of the path of `__FILE__` => *`realpath()` unnecessary*

Comment: Keep in mind `realpath` is still useful in situations where you would use the resulting `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` as a prefix to an URI. For example `$include = realpath(__DIR__ . '/path/to/file');` However as the answer describes using realpath solely with `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` is redundant.